# customizing foundation 5 top-bar with sass

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

Hello I've been trying to edit foundation 5 top-bar, I copied the entire top-bar code from the foundation.css file and placed it into the _settings.scss no matter what settings i change or edit nothing gets updated on the attached html site.

how can I edit the height of the topbar, change the background color of the entire top-nav bar. Editing the $topbar-height: 45px; doesn't quite work because it also makes the link's height that high as well, which is not what I am trying to do.

```
   .contain-to-grid {
  width: 100%;
  background: #333333; }
  .contain-to-grid .top-bar {
    margin-bottom: 0; }

.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99; }
  .fixed.expanded:not(.top-bar) {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%; }
    .fixed.expanded:not(.top-bar) .title-area {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 99; }
    .fixed.expanded:not(.top-bar) .top-bar-section {
      z-index: 98;
      margin-top: 45px; }

.top-bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  background: #333333;
  margin-bottom: 0; }
  .top-bar ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none; }
  .top-bar .row {
    max-width: none; 

}
  .top-bar form,
  .top-bar input {
    margin-bottom: 0; }
  .top-bar input {
    height: 1.8rem;
    padding-top: .35rem;
    padding-bottom: .35rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem; }
  .top-bar .button, .top-bar button {
    padding-top: 0.4125rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.4125rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 0.75rem; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
      .top-bar .button, .top-bar button {
        position: relative;
        top: -1px; } }
  .top-bar .title-area {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0em; //topbar title area
     }
  .top-bar .name {
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px; }
    .top-bar .name h1 {
      line-height: 45px;
      font-size: 1.0625rem;
      margin: 0; }
      .top-bar .name h1 a {
        font-weight: normal;
        color: white;
        width: 75%;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 15px; }
  .top-bar .toggle-topbar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0; }
    .top-bar .toggle-topbar a {
      color: white;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 0.8125rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding: 0 15px;
      height: 45px;
      line-height: 45px; }
    .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon {
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -16px; }
      .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a {
        height: 34px;
        line-height: 33px;
        padding: 0 40px 0 15px;
        color: white;
        position: relative; }
        .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a span::after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          display: block;
          height: 0;
          top: 50%;
          margin-top: -8px;
          right: 15px;
          box-shadow: 0 0px 0 1px white, 0 7px 0 1px white, 0 14px 0 1px white;
          width: 16px; }
        .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a span:hover:after {
          box-shadow: 0 0px 0 1px "", 0 7px 0 1px "", 0 14px 0 1px ""; }
  .top-bar.expanded {
    height: auto;
    background: transparent; }
    .top-bar.expanded .title-area {
      background: #333333; }
    .top-bar.expanded .toggle-topbar a {
      color: #888888; }
      .top-bar.expanded .toggle-topbar a span::after {
        box-shadow: 0 0px 0 1px #888888, 0 7px 0 1px #888888, 0 14px 0 1px #888888; }

.top-bar-section {
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  transition: left 300ms ease-out; 
}
  .top-bar-section ul {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0; 

}
  .top-bar-section .divider,
  .top-bar-section [role="separator"] {
    border-top: solid 1px #1a1a1a;
    clear: both;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%; }
  .top-bar-section ul li {
    background: #333333; }
    .top-bar-section ul li > a {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      color: white;
      padding: 12px 0 12px 0;
      padding-left: 15px;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 0.8125rem;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-transform: none; }
      .top-bar-section ul li > a.button {
        font-size: 0.8125rem;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        background-color: #008cba;
        border-color: #007095;
        color: white; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > a.button:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > a.button:focus {
          background-color: #007095; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > a.button:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > a.button:focus {
          color: white; }
      .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.secondary {
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
        border-color: #b9b9b9;
        color: #333333; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.secondary:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.secondary:focus {
          background-color: #b9b9b9; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.secondary:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.secondary:focus {
          color: #333333; }
      .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.success {
        background-color: #43ac6a;
        border-color: #368a55;
        color: white; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.success:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.success:focus {
          background-color: #368a55; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.success:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.success:focus {
          color: white; }
      .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.alert {
        background-color: #f04124;
        border-color: #cf2a0e;
        color: white; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.alert:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.alert:focus {
          background-color: #cf2a0e; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.alert:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.alert:focus {
          color: white; }
      .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.warning {
        background-color: #f08a24;
        border-color: #cf6e0e;
        color: white; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.warning:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.warning:focus {
          background-color: #cf6e0e; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.warning:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.warning:focus {
          color: white; }
    .top-bar-section ul li > button {
      font-size: 0.8125rem;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      background-color: #008cba;
      border-color: #007095;
      color: white; }
      .top-bar-section ul li > button:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > button:focus {
        background-color: #007095; }
      .top-bar-section ul li > button:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > button:focus {
        color: white; }
      .top-bar-section ul li > button.secondary {
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
        border-color: #b9b9b9;
        color: #333333; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > button.secondary:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > button.secondary:focus {
          background-color: #b9b9b9; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > button.secondary:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > button.secondary:focus {
          color: #333333; }
      .top-bar-section ul li > button.success {
        background-color: #43ac6a;
        border-color: #368a55;
        color: white; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > button.success:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > button.success:focus {
          background-color: #368a55; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > button.success:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > button.success:focus {
          color: white; }
      .top-bar-section ul li > button.alert {
        background-color: #f04124;
        border-color: #cf2a0e;
        color: white; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > button.alert:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > button.alert:focus {
          background-color: #cf2a0e; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > button.alert:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > button.alert:focus {
          color: white; }
      .top-bar-section ul li > button.warning {
        background-color: #f08a24;
        border-color: #cf6e0e;
        color: white; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > button.warning:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > button.warning:focus {
          background-color: #cf6e0e; }
        .top-bar-section ul li > button.warning:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > button.warning:focus {
          color: white; }
    .top-bar-section ul li:hover:not(.has-form) > a {
      background-color: #555555;
      background: #272727;
      color: white; }
    .top-bar-section ul li.active > a {
      background: #008cba;
      color: white; }
      .top-bar-section ul li.active > a:hover {
        background: #0078a0;
        color: white; }
  .top-bar-section .has-form {
    padding: 15px; }
  .top-bar-section .has-dropdown {
    position: relative; }
    .top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border: inset 5px;
      border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
      border-left-style: solid;
      margin-right: 15px;
      margin-top: -4.5px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0; }
    .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.moved {
      position: static; }
      .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.moved > .dropdown {
        display: block;
        position: static !important;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        overflow: visible;
        clip: auto;
        position: absolute !important;
        width: 100%; }
      .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.moved > a:after {
        display: none; }
  .top-bar-section .dropdown {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    display: block;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); }
    .top-bar-section .dropdown li {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto; }
      .top-bar-section .dropdown li a {
        font-weight: normal;
        padding: 8px 15px; }
        .top-bar-section .dropdown li a.parent-link {
          font-weight: normal; }
      .top-bar-section .dropdown li.title h5, .top-bar-section .dropdown li.parent-link {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        font-size: 1.125rem; }
        .top-bar-section .dropdown li.title h5 a, .top-bar-section .dropdown li.parent-link a {
          color: white;
          display: block; }
          .top-bar-section .dropdown li.title h5 a:hover, .top-bar-section .dropdown li.parent-link a:hover {
            background: none; }
      .top-bar-section .dropdown li.has-form {
        padding: 8px 15px; }
      .top-bar-section .dropdown li .button, .top-bar-section .dropdown li button {
        top: auto; }
    .top-bar-section .dropdown label {
      padding: 8px 15px 2px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #777777;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 0.625rem; }

.js-generated {
  display: block; }

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .top-bar {
    background: #333333;
    overflow: visible; }
    .top-bar:before, .top-bar:after {
      content: " ";
      display: table; }
    .top-bar:after {
      clear: both; }
    .top-bar .toggle-topbar {
      display: none; }
    .top-bar .title-area {
      float: left; }
    .top-bar .name h1 a {
      width: auto; }
    .top-bar input,
    .top-bar .button,
    .top-bar button {
      font-size: 0.875rem;
      position: relative;
      top: 7px; }
    .top-bar.expanded {
      background: #333333; }

  .contain-to-grid .top-bar {
    max-width: 62.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0; }

  .top-bar-section {
    transition: none 0 0;
    left: 0 !important; }
    .top-bar-section ul {
      width: auto;
      height: auto !important;
      display: inline; }
      .top-bar-section ul li {
        float: left; }
        .top-bar-section ul li .js-generated {
          display: none; }
    .top-bar-section li.hover > a:not(.button) {
      background-color: #555555;
      background: #272727;
      color: white; }
    .top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
      padding: 0 15px;
      line-height: 45px;
      background: #333333; }
      .top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):hover {
        background-color: #555555;
        background: #272727; }
    .top-bar-section li.active:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
      padding: 0 15px;
      line-height: 45px;
      color: white;
      background: #008cba; }
      .top-bar-section li.active:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):hover {
        background: #0078a0;
        color: white; }
    .top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a {
      padding-right: 35px !important; }
      .top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: inset 5px;
        border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) transparent transparent transparent;
        border-top-style: solid;
        margin-top: -2.5px;
        top: 22.5px; }
    .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.moved {
      position: relative; }
      .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.moved > .dropdown {
        display: block;
        position: absolute !important;
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        overflow: hidden;
        clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); }
    .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.hover > .dropdown, .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.not-click:hover > .dropdown {
      display: block;
      position: static !important;
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      overflow: visible;
      clip: auto;
      position: absolute !important; }
    .top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:focus + .dropdown {
      display: block;
      position: static !important;
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      overflow: visible;
      clip: auto;
      position: absolute !important; }
    .top-bar-section .has-dropdown .dropdown li.has-dropdown > a:after {
      border: none;
      content: "\00bb";
      top: 1rem;
      margin-top: -1px;
      right: 5px;
      line-height: 1.2; }
    .top-bar-section .dropdown {
      left: 0;
      top: auto;
      background: transparent;
      min-width: 100%; }
      .top-bar-section .dropdown li a {
        color: white;
        line-height: 45px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 12px 15px;
        background: #333333; }
      .top-bar-section .dropdown li:not(.has-form):not(.active) > a:not(.button) {
        color: white;
        background: #333333; }
      .top-bar-section .dropdown li:not(.has-form):not(.active):hover > a:not(.button) {
        color: white;
        background-color: #555555;
        background: #272727; }
      .top-bar-section .dropdown li label {
        white-space: nowrap;
        background: #333333; }
      .top-bar-section .dropdown li .dropdown {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0; }
    .top-bar-section > ul > .divider, .top-bar-section > ul > [role="separator"] {
      border-bottom: none;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: solid 1px #4e4e4e;
      clear: none;
      height: 45px;
      width: 0; }
    .top-bar-section .has-form {
      background: #333333;
      padding: 0 15px;
      height: 45px; }
    .top-bar-section .right li .dropdown {
      left: auto;
      right: 0; }
      .top-bar-section .right li .dropdown li .dropdown {
        right: 100%; }
    .top-bar-section .left li .dropdown {
      right: auto;
      left: 0; }
      .top-bar-section .left li .dropdown li .dropdown {
        left: 100%; }

  .no-js .top-bar-section ul li:hover > a {
    background-color: #555555;
    background: #272727;
    color: white; }
  .no-js .top-bar-section ul li:active > a {
    background: #008cba;
    color: white; }
  .no-js .top-bar-section .has-dropdown:hover > .dropdown {
    display: block;
    position: static !important;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    clip: auto;
    position: absolute !important; }
  .no-js .top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:focus + .dropdown {
    display: block;
    position: static !important;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    clip: auto;
    position: absolute !important; } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont need to copy paste the `top-bar.scss` in _settings.scss -remove it

in `_settings.scss` you have

```
$topbar-bg: $topbar-bg-color;
 $topbar-height: 45px;
```

in line 1365 and 1368.. change them to your needs